# how to achieve a selfupdating sort in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a vuex-store `game` which contains an array `players`.

Each `player` has an `id`, `name` and a `score`.

I now have a component `scoreboard` which should list all players by their score.

To sort the players, I added a computed property to my component.

When I now update a players score somewhere in the app, my computed property is not triggered. I understand that it is not triggered, since the array itself was not changed. I would need to call push/pop/shift/anything that mutates the array.

What is the common approach to solve this? Should I also mutate the array, when I update some of its properties? As the component that renders `player.points` already successfully updates, this seems dirty.

Is there a way to add more *listeners* to a computed property?

My component:

```
<template>
  <div class="scoreboard">
    <strong>Scoreboard</strong>
    <div class="scores">
      <score-board-entry v-for="player in sortedPlayers" :key="player.id" :player="player"></score-board-entry>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import _ from 'lodash'
import ScoreBoardEntry from './ScoreBoardEntry.vue'

export default {
  props: ['players'],
  data () {
    return { }
  },
  components: { ScoreBoardEntry },
  computed: {
    sortedPlayers () {
      return _.sortBy(this.players, 'score')
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

My store:

```
const initialState: state = {
  id: '',
  players: []
}

const game = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: initialState,
  mutations: {

    addPoints (state: state, payload: addPointsPayload) {
      const player = state.players.find((p) => p.id === payload.id)    
      player.points = player.points + payload.points
    }
 ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With-out seeing how you're using your score board component it's difficult to say why it's not updating.

Anyway, if you would remove the property players at your scoreBoard component and use the Vuex state players with mapState or mapGetters it will automatically update your board as soon you're changing your players data.

Another point I've detected during creating the demo below is that you're sorting by score but I think it should be points. Because there is no score property in your state or score calculation is not in your snippet.

Please have a look at the demo below or at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/k2hfay1v/).

And I think your loadash sorting is OK. I've just reversed the result to have the highest score first.

In your `addPoints` mutation method I changed to shorthand `+=` because I think that's easier to read - your version was also OK here.

The commented code in the demo at mapState or mapMutations are doing the same as the mappers and are left there to understand what the mappers are doing.

```js
const initialState = {
  id: '',
  players: [{
    id: 0,
    name: 'first',
    points: 20
  }, {
    id: 1,
    name: 'second',
    points: 10
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'third player',
    points: 35
  }]
};

const game = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: initialState,
  mutations: {
    addPoints(state, payload) {
      const player = state.players.find((p) => p.id === parseInt(payload.id));
      //console.log('addpoints', payload, player);
      player.points += payload.points;
    }
  }
};

const ScoreBoardEntry = {
  props: ['player'],
  template: `
   <div>
     Name: {{player.name}}<br/>
      Score: {{player.points}}
      <pre>Debug:
{{player}}
      </pre>
    </div>
  `
};

const scoreBoard = {
  //props: ['players'],
  template: `
   <div class="scoreboard">
    <strong>Scoreboard</strong>
    <div class="scores">
      <score-board-entry v-for="player in sortedPlayers" :key="player.id" :player="player"></score-board-entry>
    </div>
  </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {}
  },
  components: {
    ScoreBoardEntry
  },
  computed: {
    ...Vuex.mapState({
     players: (state) => state.game.players // info: mapping more complicated here because of module --> with-out module we could just use ...mapState(['players]);
    }),
    /*players() { // same as mapState
     console.log(this.$store.state.game.players);
     return this.$store.state.game.players;
    },*/
    sortedPlayers() {
      return _.sortBy(this.players, 'points').reverse(); //'score')
    }
  }
};

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    game
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  data() {
   return {
     testData: {
       id: 2,
        points: 10
      }
    };
  },
  components: {
    scoreBoard
  },
  methods: {
   /*addPoints(payload) {
     this.$store.commit('game/addPoints', payload);
    }*/
   ...Vuex.mapMutations({
     addPoints: 'game/addPoints'
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/2.3.1/vuex.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  user id: <input v-model="testData.id">
  points: <input v-model="testData.points" type="number">
  <button @click="addPoints(testData)">
  
  Add points
  </button>
  <score-board></score-board>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It really was just that my property was named wrong. (－‸ლ)

Comment: You're welcome. So where was the wrong name?  The `players` prop passed to the `scoreBoard` was not right?

Comment: Yup. When sorting `score` was wrong and `points` should have been there.